# How to create a rounded/wave rectangle like this on Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, shapes, path

I'm using inkscape and I am trying to create an structure like the one below, but all I manage to make is a disformed object.

[image]

I tried using a rectangle and combine with circles, but the best I got was this:

[image]

Comment: I'd make a curved stroke, then convert the stroke to paths.

Answer (score 13):

To deform a rectangle we need to convert it to a path first.

1. Draw and **select** rectangle.
2. Choose ***Path > Object to Path***.
3. Choose the ***Edit Path by Nodes*** tool [image] (or <kbd>F2</kbd>)
4. Select the corner nodes of the rectangle's top line

   [image]
5. Make the selected line a curve by pressing [image]
6. Push/Pull the curve handle until happy
7. Repeat step 4. to 6. for the bottom line.

   [image]
8. Add stroke color, fill color, effects

   [image]
9. For more waves add nodes to a selected line [image]

Comment: Thanks for the great tutorial, but for some reason I couldn't execute the step 5. I ended up using the DA01 suggestion. But thank you any way!

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way is to use Pattern Along Path under menu Path -> Path Effect Editor.

In this way it's easier to edit. :)

Here's the steps:

1. Create a rectangle that looks like the one you want to deform
2. Convert it to Path (menu Path => Object to Path)
3. Copy it into the clipboard
4. Create a bezier curve of the deformation
5. Select the bezier curve and go to Path -> Path Effect Editor
6. Select Pattern Along Path and click Add
7. Click on the paste icon (Check the screenshot)

[image: Deformed Rectangle]
[image: Patter Along Path]

Answer (score 3):

Just documenting the solution in the comments raised by [DA01](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/306/da01)

Draw a path:

[image]

In the **Stroke Style** tab of the **Fill and Stroke** dialog set the stroke width to super thick (I set mine to **65.000**)

[image]

Now if you want this as a shape (rather than a super thick line), just select the line, and go to **Path > Stroke to Path**:

[image]