# How to twist a complex shape in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, transform

I have a shape derived from the letter *i:*

[image: the shape]

Each of the blue “waves” and the two orange crosslinks are a path, the dot is a circle.

I want to make the shape derived from a script *i* instead, following roughly a curve like this one below the dot:

[image: a curve]

I tried using *Pattern along path,* but it ended up doing strange distortions and not what I imagined:

[image]

It is OK if it can’t be done at once, but I need to apply the same effect to all of the four paths in my shape, or maybe only to the two blue paths – I can somehow arrange the orange paths afterwards. But the blue paths are complicated, with many points, and I don’t think I will get a good effect if I try to bend them by hand.

Any ideas how to do it, if it’s possible at all?

If you want to play with the SVG original, I uploaded [the source](http://pastebin.com/eg8hkhG4) on pastebin.

This is not the same question as [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28763/how-to-create-a-rounded-wave-rectangle-like-this-on-inkscape). I assume that it is because of my complex shape instead of a simple rectangle – the solutions there don’t work for me.

---

*Update* Wrzlprmft's method produced this when used with a two-loop segment traced with Bezier curves:

[image]

Beside the strange squish, I'm still looking for a way to use it with an existing combination of curves, instead of having to redraw them using other methods.

Comment: Can you elaborate why *Pattern along path* produced dissatisfying results, preferrably by showing them? My results with this tool seemed to me to be what you want.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I added a picture. No idea how it happened, but this is what I got when I used it. And I had the whole thing selected, not just the orange part.

Comment: Take a look at [these instructions](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html). The problem is likely that you are trying to use the tool for more than one path at a time. You'll need to do each path separately.

Answer (score 5):

I just fully describe what I did to achieve something similar. You need to see which steps you can skip or need to adapt.

1. Create a rectangle.

   [image]
2. Use *Extensions → Render → Function Plotter* with these settings.

   [image]
   [image]
3. Duplicte the result and shift it horizontally as desired.
4. Select both.
5. *Path → Combine* (you can also add your orange lines here).
6. Create your *ι.*

   [image]
7. Make sure your helix is on top (press <kbd>Pos1</kbd> after having selected it).
8. Select your *ι* and your helix.
9. Use *Pattern along path* with *Single* or *Single, stretched* and *Snake.*
10. Remove the *ι.*

    [image]

Afterwards you may want to uncombine everything and give the single objects the desired style (probably done quickest with *Paste Style).*

Comment: Thank you. I tried this method. I didn't find a way to cut out two loops from the plotted line, so I retraced it with two bezier curves. They worked almost the way I wanted them to, but created an ugly sharp "miniloop", see the update in the question :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried applying Pattern along path to the object but with a small modification as follows:

1. Initially I ungrouped the object.
2. All strokes in the object were converted to path using
   Path-Stroke to path(Ctrl+Alt+C) command & were grouped.
3. Then I drew a curve(skeleton) which the pattern should follow.Lower the z-order of the curve (always the curve should be in the bottom of the Z- order with respect to the object/pattern)
4. Now I applied the pattern along path using Extension-generate from path- Pattern along path command.
5. These are the settings I applied to reproduce the required image

[image: Pattern along path]

Ensure that the option pattern is vertical is selected.

This is the image which was produced

[image]

A small distortion is still existing which can be manually adjusted.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that my Inkscape version (0.48) behaves strangely. I couldn't reproduce your method. Using "Stroke to path" does nothing, it only says "no stroked paths in this selection". And the pattern along path creates something strange, but not your result - which is what I wanted to have. I tried applying the effect in both directions (spiral to curve or curve to spiral) and didn't get it :( How are you applying the effect, is it the same way as in the tutorial Scribblemacher linked?

Comment: Edited my answer. If there is any difficulty let me know.